# Ropsten Eth getting stolen?

Tags: ropsten, hardhat

I requested Ropsten Eth from a faucet into my Ropsten address. Noticed in the activity tab that I've received the rEth but it still shows 0.

When on ropsten etherscan and found that all the ropsten I've been requesting have been transferred out to the same wallet address. I imported this wallet from hardhat node while following a tutorial from freeCodeCamp, what would be the problem here if anyone could advise?

Comment: don’t use wallets from hardhat/ganache/truffle they are probably alle deterministic generated and everyone can generate and use the same wallets

Comment: Was just following the tutorial to run a hardhat node to test script deployment, what other alternatives could you suggest some?